# error de setcookie en php

Tags: php

Porqué este código tan simple muestra error la asignar la cookie como si ya se hubiera escrito algo antes de setear la cookie

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$value = 'cualquier cosa';
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

El warning que muestra xdebug es:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /srv/http/codiad/workspace/aulamentor/php/2016/temp.php:8) in
>   /srv/http/codiad/workspace/aulamentor/php/2016/temp.php on line 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como puedes ver en la documentación de [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php), la función va a colocar la cookie para que se agregue como **parte de las cabeceras** del contenido de la respuesta. En este caso, el código que tienes ya es parte de la respuesta, y el método `setcookie` está tratando de agregar información en una respuesta que ya está escrita, por ende el mensaje de error que es completamente válido.

Asegúrate de crear las cookies antes de generar la respuesta de lado del servidor, es decir, antes de generar cualquier fragmento HTML.

Answer (score 0):

[setcookie](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php) debe llamarse antes de la salida generada, en este caso el código html.

Tomado de la documentación de PHP:

> ***setcookie()*** define una cookie para ser enviada junto con el resto de las cabeceras de HTTP. Al igual que otras cabeceras, las cookies deben ser enviadas antes de que el script genere ninguna salida (es una restricción del protocolo). Ésto implica que las llamadas a esta función se coloquen antes de que se genere cualquier salida, incluyendo las etiquetas ***<html> y <head>*** al igual que cualquier espacio en blanco.